# Trouble with basic XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm very new to using XSLT, and I'm attempting to transform a basic XML file into SQL for insertion into a database.

I'm attempting to transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DataStore xmlns="Microsystems.D3.DataEngine">
  <DDA_Atoms>
    <ID>22d2e980-f13b-43be-83a8-4b72cd38c053</ID>
    <CONTENT />
    <NAME>name 1</NAME>
    <PREVIEW>preview 1</PREVIEW>
    <STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID>1</STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID>
    <HASH>-2013036173</HASH>
    <PATH>C:\dir1</PATH>
    <SIZE>88331</SIZE>
  </DDA_Atoms>
  <DDA_Atoms>
    <ID>4a1b0532-db0c-4790-9e71-92f6d84b4ad2</ID>
    <CONTENT />
    <NAME>Name 2</NAME>
    <PREVIEW>preview 2</PREVIEW>
    <STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID>2</STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID>
    <HASH>-1467957647</HASH>
    <PATH>C:\dir2</PATH>
    <SIZE>220557</SIZE>
  </DDA_Atoms>
</DataStore>
```

using the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:template match="DataStore">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DDA_Atoms">
    <xsl:text>INSERT INTO DDA_Atoms VALUES ('</xsl:text >
        <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
        <xsl:text>', '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="CONTENT"/>
        <xsl:text>', '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
        <xsl:text>', '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="PREVIEW"/>
        <xsl:text>', </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="HASH"/>
        <xsl:text>, '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="PATH"/>
        <xsl:text>', </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="SIZE"/>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I run the XSL on the XML it comes back with just the value of the nodes and not the literal SQL text. What's more, it seems that it's in fact ignoring all the XSL, as when I remove all the template match code and leave essentially an empty XSL document, the transform does exactly the same thing: merely returns all the values of the nodes as in:

```
22d2e980-f13b-43be-83a8-4b72cd38c053name 1preview 11-2013036173C:\dir1883314a1b0532-db0c-4790-9e71-92f6d84b4ad2Name 2preview 22-1467957647C:\dir2220557
```

I assume my template matches are 'missing' their targets or something. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the namespace declaration in your XML

```
<DataStore xmlns="Microsystems.D3.DataEngine">
```

This means this element, and all its descendants belong to this namespace. However, there is no reference to the namespace in your XSLT, and so all your xpath expressions are looking for elements with no namespace, and will not match your XML. You are getting text output simply because XSLT's built-in templates will be used instead, and these will output text nodes where they find any.

What you need to do is first declare the namespace in your XSLT, with a namespace prefix

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
                xmlns:da="Microsystems.D3.DataEngine">
```

Then, you wherever your refer to an element, you need to prefix it with the namespace prefix. For example:

```
<xsl:template match="da:DataStore">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:da="Microsystems.D3.DataEngine">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:template match="da:DataStore">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="da:DDA_Atoms">
    <xsl:text>INSERT INTO DDA_Atoms VALUES ('</xsl:text >
        <xsl:value-of select="da:ID"/>
        <xsl:text>', '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="da:CONTENT"/>
        <xsl:text>', '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="da:NAME"/>
        <xsl:text>', '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="da:PREVIEW"/>
        <xsl:text>', </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="da:STRUCTURE_ELEMENT_ID"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="da:HASH"/>
        <xsl:text>, '</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="da:PATH"/>
        <xsl:text>', </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="da:SIZE"/>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note there is no need for the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in the second template, as you are already handling all the children anyway.

Note: If you were using XSLT 2.0, you could use the "xpath-default-namespace" option, to declare a default namespace. Then you wouldn't have to change any of templates to use a namespace prefix, as XSLT would then assume any without a prefix were in this default namespace (as opposed to being in no namespace).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
                xpath-default-namespace="Microsystems.D3.DataEngine">
```